# How to get result as List<Object> in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am new to hibernate.

I have these two classes defined:

```
   public class User{
       String email;
       Company company;
   }; 

   public class Company{
      long id;
      String name;
   }
```

I want to get all the users corresponding to particular company id.

createSQLQuery returns a simple list:

```
session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE company_id="+id).list();
```

How can I get `List<User>` using hibernate criteria or HQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HQL: (better, is like sql)

```
Query q = getSession().createQuery("select u from User u inner join u.company c where c.id = :id");
q.setParameter("id", id);
List<User> list = q.list();
```

HQL:

```
Query q = getSession().createQuery("select u from User u where u.company.id = :id");
q.setParameter("id", id);
List<User> list = q.list();
```

Criteria:

```
List<User> list = getSession().createCriteria(User.class).createCriteria("company").add(Restrictions.eq("id", id)).list();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it in HQL:

```
List users = session.createQuery("FROM User WHERE company.id = " + id).list();
```

The result list is simply the return value of the 
[list()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#list()) method you are already calling in your code snippet.

Unfortunately it's not type-safe. I suggest [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/) and/or [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) to perform type-safe queries. They are built on top of JPA.

Just another tip: Always use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try This on First:

```
session.createQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE company_id=" + companyName).List<User>();
```

If you could get your result the try following way

I am assuming that you have unitOfWork context and these classes are your entities. Now update your classes like this, then you can get more and more as you want.

public class User

```
    {
        public String Email { get; set; }
        public Company company { get; set; }
    };

    public class Company
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public IList<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
public IList<User> GetompanyUsers(int Id)
        {
            return unitOfWork.Session().QueryOver<Company>().Where(c => c.Id == Id).Select(c=>c.Users).List<User>();
        }
```